# Cordova.FileSystem getting device root

Tags: android, cordova

I have the following problem using Cordova.FileSystem: regardless of what I do it seems I cannot get in the device root i'm always getting /storage/emulated/0. The documentation for this API is a bit sparse so I hope that somebody here will be able to bring me further. Here is what I have so far:

```
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail);
    }, false);
   function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {

        fileSystem.root.getDirectory("", { create: false, exclusive: false }, getDirSuccess, fail);
    }
    function getDirSuccess(dirEntry) {
        var directoryReader = dirEntry.createReader();
        directoryReader.readEntries(readerSuccess, fail);
    }

Config.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.wakeme920893" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>WakeMe</name>
  <description>
        An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
    </description>
  <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">
      Ionic Framework Team
    </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal" />
  <preference name="iosExtraFilesystems" value="library,library-nosync,documents,documents-nosync,cache,bundle,root" />
  <preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="root" />
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
  </feature>
  <cdv:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
  <cdv:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing" />
  <feature name="Contacts">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVContacts" />
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.contacts.ContactManager"/>
  </feature>
</widget>
```

Comment: can you show us the entries in your config.xml file?

Comment: I´ve added the config.xml :)

Comment: Do you want to have access to file:///android_asset/data/data/<app-id>/ ? I recommend to use the  <platform> tag in your config.xml 

example:
<platform name="ios">
....
    </platform>
    <platform name="android">
...
    </platform>

Comment: I want to read the file:///system/media/audio/ringtones folder. the <platform> tag has the problem not resolved. When i change the "AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value or the "AndroidExtraFilesystems" value in the config.xml to root, documents or anything else, it doesn´t change the location. I always getting  /storage/emulated/0.